# Empty cursor for iteration using zip

Tags: python-3.x, iterator

I have multiple cursors for iteration but when one of them is empty, the zip is not working. How can I iterate through other lists when one is empty.
Sample code looks like below:

```
    for x, y, p, q in zip(cursor_X, cursor_Y,
                              cursor_P, cursor_Q):
    data1 = x
    data2 = y
    data3 = p
    data4 = q
print(str(data1['data']), end="")
print("\t" + str(data2['data']), end="")
print("\t" + str(data2['data']), end="")
print("\t" + str(data2['data']))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

> itertools.zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None)
>
> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
> If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in
> with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is
> exhausted

You didn't show what your data looks like, but in order to make the rest of your code work, you could use a dict with a `'data'` key and an empty string as value for missing data:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

for x, y, p, q in zip_longest(cursor_X, cursor_Y,
                              cursor_P, cursor_Q,
                              fillvalue={'data':''}):
    data1 = x
    data2 = y
    data3 = p
    data4 = q

    print(str(data1['data']), end="")
    print("\t" + str(data2['data']), end="")
    print("\t" + str(data2['data']), end="")
    print("\t" + str(data2['data']))
```

Note that you could rewrite the content of the loop without unnecessary intermediate variables:

```
for x, y, p, q in zip_longest(cursor_X, cursor_Y, cursor_P, cursor_Q,
                              fillvalue={'data':''}):    
    out = '\t'.join(map(str, (x, y, z, t)))
    print(out)
```

or even:

```
for items in zip_longest(cursor_X, cursor_Y, cursor_P, cursor_Q,
                         fillvalue={'data':''}):    
    out = '\t'.join(map(str, items))
    print(out)
```